# R.java file from Android library project not importing into application project

Tags: android, reference

I followed the instructions here on how to create an Android library project, and use it in an Android application:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html

but it is not working. I can see the library project is added to my application but I cannot reference anything in it because it won't build. The R.java file from the lib is NOT being added to my application project, so the lib project contains tons of errors, everywhere it tries to reference it's own R.java file.

I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but in the console there are messages stating that the there is "No resource identifier found for attribute 'X' in package 'Lib Package'. My library package has a a few styleable attributes defined for a custom view I made, all of which are being complained about in this console message. The library builds just fine, and I don't get those messages in the console until I hook the library to my application, so I don't know what's up with this.

I really would like to get this working. I've spent two entire days on it, to no avail. Please offer any ideas you might have to help!

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm not using custom attributes. I just want my libraries R visible in my main application. It seems that Eclipse generates the _src file correctly, but the R class, generated inside the libraries /gen folder, doesn't get linked inside my main project. What should I do? I don't want to link it myself, it would break things later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to my conundrum was that the library had an attrs.xml file that defined a few custom attributes for a custom view I created. I removed attrs.xml and hardcoded the values in the custom view code, rebuilt the library, and problem solved.

This isn't cool though, what this means is that custom views with custom attributes can't be used in libraries. I hope Google fixes this.

Comment: i have not use any attrs.xml,but my application not get build,how can i refer the other java classes (which are not extend by activity or service or receiver)

Comment: @ChristopherPerry Have you [or do you know of] submitted a bug report? I agree, Google should fix this. Being unable to implement custom views in a library is completely nonsensical.

Comment: Well, you can implement custom views as long as you don't try to define any custom attributes to use in your view. The way I was using this library is a bit questionable anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a matter of file duplicity. You can't build a project that contains more than one instance of the same file. Due to the nature of an android project XML files are usually the first the negate a successful build.

Comment: The resources are supposed to be merged between your library projects and your application project. For some reason I don't care to look into at the moment, attributes were not merging.

Comment: You *can* build a project with more than one instance of the same file - for example, `splashscreen_lite.png` and `splashscreen_pro.png`.  As @Eitan Schwartz says, these will be merged at build time, with the application project resources taking precedence over the library project resources.