# Custom state drawables not working in Library Projects

Tags: android, state, drawable

Any searches for any information on how to provide your own custom state for use in a drawable state list selector pulls up very little but almost all of them (here and elsewhere) refer to this [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uqr2BNI7NZo).

I have getters and setters like this:  (Not included in the above post, but using their wording to keep it simple)

```
public void setFried(boolean fried){
    if(mFried != fried){
        mFried = fried;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }
}

public void isFried(){
    return mFried;
}
```

I have been trying to get it to work for the last couple hours and nothing seems to be working.  It just simply does not change the appearance.  I watched what happened as it called onCreateDrawableState(), and I watched what would come out of getDrawableState() after I changed the custom state.  The custom state values are in fact appearing in the drawableState array.

Since I can see the state is actually being merged into the array, and since it seems to be completely ignoring any of my custom state in the selector, I think the xml must be wrong.

Here is what the post suggested:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.app.package">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_baked" state_baked="true"
      state_fried="false" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_fried" state_baked="false"
      state_fried="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_overcooked" state_baked="true"
      state_fried="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_raw" state_baked="false"
      state_fried="false" />
</selector>
```

Can you really just write state_fried and state_baked or do they need a prefix like app:state_fried?  If I try adding a prefix I get a Console error like: `No resource identifier found for attribute 'state_fried' in package my.app.package`

Has anyone actually got custom states to work?  Is the referenced post all you need to get this to work or is there something wrong with it or missing?

I don't know if it makes any difference but I am using an Android Library Project and the selector and the attr.xml is in the Library project.

Thanks

**Update**
Looks like the problem is that Library Projects don't play well with custom attributes.  See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fc9ac9f168a2ec4f/33ac0c1a69e8d86c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432649/r-java-file-from-android-library-project-not-importing-into-application-project), [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656).

Haven't seen much of a workaround unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote that original question. IIRC, that was when Android was in beta, and things have changed a bit. Custom attributes do indeed work; I use them. You do indeed need the `app:` prefix for custom state attributes. You also need to substitute your app's package in place of `my.app.package` in the xmlns declaration.

Comment: well on behalf of all developers I thank you for asking it because it is the only source on the entire interwebs that contained any hint of how to do it!  I used my.app.package in the question for the sake of the example.  I do have my package name there and I still get the error.  Would using an Android Library Project be the reason?  I guess I'll experiment more with this in mind.

Comment: Make sure that you declared the attribute names in a `declare-styleable` section in `values/attr.xml`. I've never tried this with a library project, but I don't see why it should be any different; libraries can have resources as easily as applications.

Comment: after experimenting with this more, it looks like it is a issue with the library project setup.  I'm not sure how to resolve it yet but I'll post something if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/my.app.package
```

for attributes declared in the library.

Comment: This answer is not correct. It allows your dependent projects to build, but they will not read the state values. Instead, use: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/my.app.package`.